# Поиск элементов по введённому тексту React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

В React native новичок и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно реализовать своеобразный SearchBar, поиск по элементам. Реализовывал так:

```
 это сам компонент:
<TextInput 
      onChangeText={text=>{search(text)}}
    />


функция, которая в него передаётся: 


const search=function(text=true){
  let result=text;
  return result;
  }

и функция, которая отрисовывает и фильтрует элементы:
const foo = state.
  filter(el=>{if(search()==true){
  return true;}
   else{el.name.includes(search())}}).
  map((item)=>(<Item item={item} key={item.id}/>));
```

Как я понял проблема в том, что функция foo отрабатывает только один раз, отрисовывая весь список, а при вводе текста в TextInput не отрабатывает заново и не перерисовывает всё по новой. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

1. Первый способ я думаю, это просто засунуть логику поиска в onChangeText

```js
// хуки, почитать про них тут https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 

// Пример иморта Ваших компонентов
import Item from "./components/Item";
import TextInput from "./components/TextInput"

// функциональный компонент
export default function App() {
  // инициализируем переменные и фукнции, которые могут их изменить
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  
  // второй аргумент [], следовательно выполняется только при загрузке 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Boolean(text.lenght)) {
      return;
    }
    // тут просто выполняем Вашу логику
    const searchFoo = state
      .filter((el) => el.name.includes(search()))
      .map((item) => <Item item={item} key={item.id} />);

    setFoo(searchFoo);
  }, []);

  const search = function (text = "") {
    // Тут проверяем на длину
    if (Boolean(text.lenght)) {
      return;
    }
    // Тепрь запоминаем текст, для того, чтобы можно было его достать в любой момент
    setText(text);

    // тут просто выполняем Вашу логику
    const searchFoo = state
      .filter((el) => {
          el.name.includes(search());
      })
      .map((item) => <Item item={item} key={item.id} />);
    setFoo(searchFoo); // foo теперь можно использовать
  };
  return (
    <TextInput 
      onChangeText={text=>{search(text)}}
    />
  );
}
```

2. Теперь способ, который больше похож на правду

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import TextInput from "./components/TextInput"

export default function App() {

  const [foo, setFoo] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  
  // Когда измениться text, выполниться эта функция 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Boolean(text.lenght)) {
      return;
    }
    // Ваша логика поиска
    const searchFoo = state
      .filter((el) => el.name.includes(search()))
      .map((item) => <Item item={item} key={item.id} />);

    setFoo(searchFoo); // можем использовать foo
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <TextInput 
      onChangeText={text=>setText(text)}
    />
  );
}
```

Не стоит пренебрегать хуками, очень полезный инструмент, с помощью которого можно организовать реактивность

Comment: Забыл дополнить, хуки React, работают так-же и в ReactNative